# Rails & Bootstrap Make button inline with text field

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a front end of web app. I would like to know how to make the button and textfield in line. Another question is how to make the error message displayed just below the textfield?
Picture: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vsdy3730flraes3/Screen%20Shot%202013-12-01%20at%204.47.20%20PM.png

Here is the code:

```
    <div class="input-group" align="center" >

    <%= form_tag(location_search_path,method: "get" ) do %>
        <%= text_field_tag('location', params[:location], :size => 150, :placeholder=> "Enter city or zip code") %> 
        <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn  btn-success ") do %>
         Search 
                 <i class="icon-search"></i>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
    <% [:notice, :error, :alert].each do |level| %>
      <% unless flash[level].blank? %>
              <div data-alert="alert" class="alert-message <%= flash_class(level) %> fade in" align="center">
          <%= content_tag :p, flash[level] %>
      </div>
     <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `<div class="form-inline">` to your form element to get the button and field onto the same line, and I guess you could us a `<p>` to make the message appear below it, though I would probably set up the input group in a row with columns to center it rather than the align tag you are using, and then put the messages into a new `<row>` below it in the same column.

```
<div class="input-group" align="center" >
    <div class="form-inline">
      <%= form_tag(location_search_path,method: "get" ) do %>
      <%= text_field_tag('location', params[:location], :size => 150, :placeholder=> "Enter city or zip code") %> 
      <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn  btn-success ") do %>
       Search 
             <i class="icon-search"></i>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    <% [:notice, :error, :alert].each do |level| %>
        <% unless flash[level].blank? %>
        <div data-alert="alert" class="alert-message <%= flash_class(level) %> fade in" align="center">
        <%= content_tag :p, flash[level] %>
        </div>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you give me furthur directions on how to use <row> and <col>? I'm really new to Bootstrap. Thanks!

Comment: The most basic explanation is that a row is 12 columns wide.You nest columns in rows, declaring how many columns wide it is. If you were splitting the page in half you would have set of row tags and inside that would be a column of "6" and another column of "6". It's really an important principle in the layout of Bootstrap and beyond the scope of this comment. You HAVE to watch http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics if you haven't already. Also switch to 3.0 if you haven't gotten too far with 2.3 because upgrading later is very hard.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will switch to 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap 3 has input groups... which are nice.  http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Try this in your code...

```
<%= form_tag location_search_path, method: 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :location, params[:location], size: 150, placeholder: "Enter city or zip code" %>
  <span class='input-group-btn'>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```